# error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'double'

Tags: c++

```
string mesag="";
mesag="aDoubleArray value at 0------->"<<aDoubleArray[0]<<"   aDoubleArray value at 1 is "<<aDoubleArray[1];
addLog(AMR_LT_WARN, mesag);// this part not working 
addLog(AMR_LT_WARN, "this works well");
```

i dont know anythng about c++ just want to print aDoubleArray values to log file but it throws 
 error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'double'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something like the following:

```
char message[100];
sprintf(message, "aDoubleArray value at 0-------> %g   aDoubleArray value at 1 is %g", aDoubleArray[0], aDoubleArray[1]);

std::string mesag(message);
addLog(AMR_LT_WARN, mesag);// this part not working 
addLog(AMR_LT_WARN, "this works well");
```

Comment: iostreams would probably be preferable, as then you'll avoid type error such as %d, which isn't a double.

Comment: i tried above but it gives below error                              error C2664: 'addLog' : cannot convert param
eter 2 from 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' to 'const char *'
     [exec]         No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: Change that to `addLog(AMR_LT_WARN, mesag.c_str());`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use string streams to do that. Include `sstream` and you can do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main(void) {
    double d = 3.14159;         // this is the double.
    std::stringstream ss;       // this is the stream.
    ss << "Double is " << d;    // Send normal output to stream.
    std::cout << "["            // Use str() to get underlying string.
              << ss.str()
              << "]"
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This sets the stringstream to contain `"Double is 3.14159"` and outputs that enclosed in square brackets:

```
[Double is 3.14159]
```

Answer (score 1):

you are treating "aDoubleArray value at 0-------->" as a stream.  Const strings aren't input streams.  Check out http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/strings/stringstream.html as stringstreams might be what you want.